# SignalR not working with Hangfire (Asp.net)

Tags: notifications, signalr, hangfire

I am trying to use Hangfire to schedule a notification with SignalR.
For some odd reason, the notifications through SignalR work completely fine if Hangfire is not involved. When I involve Hanfire(tried enqueue, schedule), the method gets called for sure(I check a separate log file), and yet the notifications are not sent out to the clients…

How I am using Hangfire enqueue/schedule?

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => SendNotifications(notification));
```

The method:

```
public void SendNotifications(Notification notification)
{
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext().Clients.All.Invoke(“notification”, notification);
}
```

The Hangfire dashboard doesn’t register any problems.
Like I said, I tried calling the method directly, without Hangfire, and it works as expexted.

It would be great if anyone could help me find the problem, and solution. Thank you! :)

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution? I have to do something similar. Thanks.

Comment: Hello! I did find a solution, but it was not as simple as I thought. Basically, I had to create a whole new controller specifically for the notifications. So you schedule a method, from whichever service you like, and then, in that scheduled method, once it gets called with Hangfire, you use an httpclient to call the endpoint from the new NotificationsClient controller, and in that controller endpoint you can finally do this: public void SendNotifications(Notification notification)
{
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext().Clients.All.Invoke(“notification”, notification);
}